# How to validate request data, push another to array after validation and create object in a nice way in Laravel 6

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation

I'd like to validate data, then create slugs after validation and create object in a nice way.

This is not the solution I am excepting:

```
public function store()
{
 data = request()->validate([
   'name_en' => 'required',
   'name_de' => 'required'
 ]);
 $data['slug_en'] = Str::slug(request()->name_en);
 $data['slug_de'] = Str::slug(request()->name_de);

 Post::create( $data );   
}
```

I' like to achieve the same in this way:

```
public function store()
{
Post::create( request()->validate([
  'name_en' => 'required',
  'name_de' => 'required'
]) );

//where to place slugs creation?

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the first snippet?

Comment: what kind of error do you get in web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way you can do this in Laravel is with [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation). You can create a class for your request that extends the FormRequest class (let's assume you call it `StorePost` for this example).

In this class, you can use the `rules` method to put you validation rules, like so:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name_en' => 'required',
        'name_de' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

To add the `slug_` keys, you can use the [prepareForValidation method](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#prepare-input-for-validation). This method can be used to add data to the request with the `merge` method, e.g.:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'slug_en' => Str::slug($this->name_en),
        'slug_de' => Str::slug($this->name_de)
    ]);
}
```

Because this happens before validation, you can even add validation to your `slug_` keys in the `rules()` method.

So to actually use this class, you can simply typehint the class name in your controller method using Laravel magic. Your really neat controller can now look like the following:

```
public function store(StorePost $request)
{
    Post::create($request->all()); // or specify the keys you want inside the `all()` method
    // ...
}
```

And it's as simple as that! The validation of the form request will actually happen before the controller method is run, so you can be sure the validated data will be correct.

Of course, you can add any methods you want inside the form request class, so there are many different ways you could achieve this, e.g. with a `getPostData` method that returns an array with the slug values included.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a class named [TransformsRequest](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.html);

It can automatically filter and deal with every fields in your request.

I think you can create a **middleware** like `SlugStrings.php` and **extend TransformsRequest**.

So **every request's key value will be transform by `slug`**.

1. create `app/Http/Middleware/SlugStrings.php` file:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class SlugStrings extends TransformsRequest
{
    /**
     * The names of the attributes that should be slug.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $only = [
        'name_en',
        'name_de',
    ];

   /**
     * Transform the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->only, true)) {
            return is_string($value) ? Str::slug($value) : $value;
        } else {
            return $value;
        }
    }
}
```

2. Add this middleware to `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```php
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        ...
        // Add it here:
        \App\Http\Middleware\SlugStrings::class,
        ...
    ];
```

Now you can do nothing with the fields `name_en` and `name_de`, just create them from request:

```php
public function store()
{
Post::create( request()->validate([
  'name_en' => 'required',
  'name_de' => 'required'
]) );
}
```

It's pretty easy.

So next time you have another field, and you want to slug it. Just add it in `$only` attribute.